# AngularJS navigation from states directive, the right way

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to make a directive, which would take the Angular UI-Router states information and based on that create a navbar. Now what would we the right way?

`a)` Create NavController with `$state` dependency, take the state information and convert it into suitable JS array in it, and then pass this array to the directive trough the attributes and do the DOM manipulation there.

`b)` Create a NavDirective, with a `$state` dependency, and do all the work (states information transformation and DOM manipulation) in it.

What would be suggested as a good practice?

Now I have the following:

```
app.directive('navigation', ['$parse', '$compile', function ($parse, $compile) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.selectedNode = null;


        scope.$watch(attrs.menuData, function (val) {
            var template = angular.element(
                '<ul class="nav navbar-nav">'
                + '<li ng-repeat="node in ' + attrs.menuData + '" active-tab="{{node.href}}">'
                + '<a ui-sref="{{node.state}}"><b>{{node.text}}</b></a>'
                + '</li>'
                + '</ul>'
            );

            var linkFunction = $compile(template);

            linkFunction(scope);
            element.html(null).append( template );
        }, true);
    }
};
```

}]);

```
app.controller('NavigationController', ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {

    var menu = [];
    var states = $state.get();

    _.each(states, function(state, key) {
        if(!_.isObject(state) || _.has(state, 'abstract') || _.has(state, 'parent')) {
            return;
        }

        var object = {
            text: _.has(state.data, 'title') ? state.data.title : '(no title)',
            state: state.name,
            href: state.url
        }

        menu.push(object);
    });

    $scope.menu = menu;
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Controller should generally not be used to perform DOM-manipulation.

From the angular developer guide:

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller

> ### Do not use controllers to:
>
> Manipulate DOM — Controllers should contain only business logic. Putting any presentation logic into Controllers significantly affects its testability. Angular has databinding for most cases and directives to encapsulate manual DOM manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

This is the v2 for the directive. Is that the right way of doing directive in angular?

```
app.directive('navigation', ['$parse', '$compile', function ($parse, $compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        templateUrl: 'views/widgets/navbar.html',
        replace: true,
        scope: {},
        controller: ['$scope', '$state', function ($scope, $state) {
            var menu = [];
                var states = $state.get();

            _.each(states, function(state, key) {
                if(!_.isObject(state) || _.has(state, 'abstract') || _.has(state, 'parent')) {
                    return;
                }

                var object = {
                    text: _.has(state, 'data') && _.has(state.data, 'title') 
                            ? state.data.title : '(no title)',
                    state: state.name,
                    href: state.url
               }

               menu.push(object);
            });

            $scope.nav = {};
            $scope.nav.menu = menu;
        }],
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.nav.brand = attrs.navBrand; 
            console.log(scope);
        }
    };
 }]);
```

The template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">{{ nav.brand }}</a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-repeat="node in nav.menu" active-tab="{{node.href}}">
            <a ui-sref="{{node.state}}"><b>{{node.text}}</b></a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

And the directive call:

```
<div navigation nav-brand="My Brand"></div>
```